# Java Programs won't run

Tags: java, eclipse, command-prompt

Earlier today, my programs ran with eclipse and command prompt. None of my programs work with eclipse, and my first program, HelloWorld, works with command prompt. I have checked, and yes, I have everything installed properly. I have checked again and again that I am spelling things correctly in cmd, and have the right directory. I restarted my computer as well. When I hover over the "run" button in eclipse, it says my program is running. My program has worked before. Thanks in advance!

This is something that shows up in "Problems":

Description Resource Path Location Type Build path specifies execution environment CDC-1.1/Foundation-1.1. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment. JAVA Programs Build path JRE System Library Problem

Code for a program that won't run:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
public class randomdemo { 
    public static void randommethod()
    {   
        List<Integer> myArray = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> evenArray = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> oddArray = new ArrayList<>();


        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int n = rand.nextInt(25);

            myArray.add(n);

            if(n % 2 == 0)
            {
                evenArray.add(n);
            }
            else
            {
                oddArray.add(n);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("All: " + myArray);
        System.out.println("Even: " + evenArray);
        System.out.println("Odd: " + oddArray);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        randommethod();

    }
}
```

Comment: There should be a tab labeled "Problems".  Does anything show up there?

Comment: If eclipse says the program is already running, then there is some old version of it that is running - maybe waiting for input or something. On the right side of the console pane, click on the two `X` symbols. If there is a running program, a red box should appear. Click on it to stop the program, the try your programs again.

Comment: ajb, I edited the question -- there is somethng in problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of things to consider:

1. Do you have a valid JDK installed? You can check `C:\Program Files\Java` or `C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\` for a jdk folder.
2. In eclipse, right click the Java Project, > `Build Path` > `Configure Build Path...` This should open up a `Java Build Path` window.

   In here, click the `Libraries` tab. If there are now `JRE System Library` entries, click `Add Library...` > `JRE System Library` > `Next` and you can either pick `Workspace default JRE` which should be something like `jre1.8.0_25` or, you can select `Execution environment`. If you select the latter, click the `Environments...` button, and select the `JavaSE-*` version that you would like.